# How can I add Google map and some co-ordinates in electronjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have written following code. How can I add Google map and some co-ordinates in electronjs. The generated error is mentioned below,

```
  const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
    const url = require('url')
    const path = require('path')
    const {Menu} = require('electron')
    const loadGoogleMapsApi = require('load-google-maps-api')

    let win

    app.on('ready',function() {
       win = new BrowserWindow({})
       win.loadURL(url.format ({
          pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'home.html'),
          protocol: 'file:',
          slashes: true
       }));
    });

    loadGoogleMapsApi().then(function (googleMaps) {
    new googleMaps.Map(document.querySelector('.map'), {
     center: {
       lat: 40.7484405,
       lng: -73.9944191
     },
     zoom: 12
    })
    }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error)
    })
```

### I don't Know How to solve this...

It generates the error which is mentioned as below,

Reference Error:

```
window is not defined
 at /home/ebuilders/Desktop/ElectronApplication/node_modules/load-google-maps-api/index.js:19:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/home/ebuilders/Desktop/ElectronApplication/node_modules/load-google-maps-api/index.js:11:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ebuilders/Desktop/ElectronApplication/process.js:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ebuilders/Desktop/ElectronApplication/process.js:31:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I recommend you to take a look at what electron is: https://electronjs.org/ . It looks like you are confusing the **main** and the **renderer**. The main process cannot access the renderer process directly, you need to rely on the `renderer` process (look at your index.html) in order to load the map. If you can't find the documentation you're looking for in the official electron page, you can take a look at this article: https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2

Comment: Also please take the tour about how to ask an appropriate question, particularly how to create a minimal complete verifiable example (MVCE) of the problem. This will help us help you more effectively, and creating a MVCE will frequently allow you to solve the problem yourself without assistance.